# QR decoding with zbar

Tags: c++, qr-code, zbar

I'm encoding a byte array into qr code using libqrencode and than try to decode it using zbar library. the programming language is c++.

The problem occurs when the values are >=128. for example when I decode the qr code which contains the following values:

```
unsigned char  data[17]={111, 127, 128, 224, 255, 178, 201,200, 192, 191,22, 17,20, 34, 65 ,23, 76};
```

`symbol->get_data_length()` return  25 instead of 17 and when I tried to print the values using this small piece of code:

```
string input_data = symbol->get_data();
for(int k=0; k< 25; k++)
   cout<< (int)((unsigned char)input_data[k])<<", ";
```

I got the following result:

```
111, 127, 194, 128, 195, 160, 195, 191, 194, 178, 195, 137, 195, 136, 195, 128, 194, 191, 22, 17, 20, 34, 65, 23, 76,
```

So as we can notice the values < 128 didn't effected but I got two bytes for every value >=128.
Also I printed the values without casting to unsigned char:

```
for(int k=0; k< 25; k++)
   cout<< (int)input_data[k]<<", ";
```

and the result is:

```
111, 127, -62, -128, -61, -96, -61, -65, -62, -78, -61, -119, -61, -120, -61, -128, -62, -65, 22, 17, 20, 34, 65, 23, 76
```

I solve this problem by the following code:

```
void process_zbar_output(const string & input_data, vector<unsigned char> & output_data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input_data.length(); i++)
        {
            int temp = (int) input_data[i];
 // if the original value is >=128 we need to process it to get the original value
            if (temp < 0)
            {
                // if the number is 62 than the original is between 128 and 191
                // if the number is 61 than the original is between 192 and 255
                if (temp == -62)
                    output_data.push_back(256 + ((int) input_data[i + 1]));
                else
                    output_data.push_back(256 + ((int) input_data[i + 1] + 64));
                i++;

            }
            else
            {
                output_data.push_back( input_data[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me with this problem and explain why I got these extra bytes?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on when reading them in, I'm not familiar with those libraries. But for printing them out... 194 is 11000010 in binary which is -62 with two's complement... so that should steer you in the correct direction for your second issue.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: yes, it is the  two's complement. but the problem is that the decoded value are (194, 128 when casting to uchar) or (-62, -128 without casting to uchar) instead of 128. So I used the values (-62, -128) in my function "process_zbar_output" to get the original value.
Moreover  I can get the original values in range [128..191] from the second component (194, 128) and it is true for all values in this range. But that isn't true for values in range [192..255].